# Wordpress meta_query OR/AND relations not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a search form with multiple options that are taxonomies. When I select all options, or just one, and click search it never returns any record. I have a problem with understanding relations, and how to properly set arrays.

```
$args = array('post_type' => array( 'property' ),
    'order'             =>  'DESC',
    'orderby'           =>  'post_date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
         array(
             array(
                 'key'       => 'property_address_postal_code',
                 'value'     => $search,
                 'compare'   => 'LIKE',
             ),
             array(
                 'key'       => 'property_address_state',
                 'value'     => $search,
                 'compare'   => 'LIKE',
             ),
             array(
                'key'       => 'property_location',
                'value'     => $search,
                'compare'   => 'LIKE',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'       => 'property_price',
                    'value'     => array($_GET['min-price'],$_GET['max-price']),
                    'type'    => 'numeric',
                    'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'       => 'property_price',
                    'value'     => array($_GET['min-price'],$_GET['max-price']),
                    'type'    => 'numeric',
                    'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'm not sure if you're quite understanding how the relation property applies in this function. It applies `AND/OR` to other properties on the same level. So your very first `relation => AND` makes sure your `$search` variable matches one of the properties you specify AND that the `property_price` is between the min and max values.

Secondly, with subsequent, nested meta queries, the default relation is `AND`, so when you try to match `$search` against different properties, you're actually trying to make sure that `$search` is matching ALL of the properties you specify. You can fix that by trying to match `$search` against one property OR another property.

Thirdly, with your comparison of the price against the min and max price, the meta query is malformed, and both of those meta queries are identical. In that case, you don't need a relation since you only have to check against one value.

You can simplify your code as such:

```
$args = array('post_type' => array( 'property' ),
    'order'             =>  'DESC',
    'orderby'           =>  'post_date',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
         array(
             'relation' => 'OR',
             array(
                 'key'       => 'property_address_postal_code',
                 'value'     => $search,
                 'compare'   => 'LIKE',
             ),
             array(
                 'key'       => 'property_address_state',
                 'value'     => $search,
                 'compare'   => 'LIKE',
             ),
             array(
                'key'       => 'property_location',
                'value'     => $search,
                'compare'   => 'LIKE',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'property_price',
            'value'     => array($_GET['min-price'],$_GET['max-price']),
            'type'      => 'numeric',
            'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
        )
    )
);
```

Now, you're making a query that checks if `$search` is like `property_address_potal_code` OR like `property_address_state` OR like `property_location` AND `property_price` is between the min and max price.

You might still have to fiddle with it a bit depending on other logic in your code, but I think this should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, youre my star. Everything is exactly as you say, i understand relations in SQL queries, but in Wordpress meta_query i don't. Once again thank you for solution.

Comment: I like to think of the meta query function similarly to PHP `implode()` in that the `relation` glues each meta query together using that specific relation as the delimiter. I hope that helps you understand the function a little better!